# best practice for api data validation

Tags: typescript, api, nestjs

I'm  working on creating   `api`  with `nestjs` , but when it comes to data validation it becomes so confused because of many options existing ,
for example should i validate data in rout level using schema validation (like `hapi@joi`)
or validate data in class level class-validator

`

```
use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    console.log('the method is', req.method);

const userSchema = joi.object({
  name: joi
    .string()
    .alphanum()
    .min(3)
    .max(15)
    .required(),
  phone: joi
    .number()
    .min(11)
    .required(),
  password: joi
    .string()
    .min(8)
    .max(100)
    .required()
    .regex(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\w+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/),
});
const { error } = userSchema.validate(req.body);
if (error) {
  throw new BadRequestException(error.details);
}
next();
```

`

validation on class level

`

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Matches(/((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\w+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/)
  password: string;

  @IsNumber()
  @Length(11, 15)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  phone: number;
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

It's a personal preference and it depends a lot on your project structure, but...

Using DTOs to validate your objects makes your code cleaner IMHO and simplifies the usage of the [nest OpenAPI plugin (used for documentation)](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction). And also, since if we remove the decorators, it is nothing more than a simple class with properties, you could also use it as your type on the parameters of your functions just like -> https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters allowing typescript to infer the type of the object and allowing you to be sure it's already validated

Comment: I'm already read the documentation before but i'm asking for best practice for example,What about performance? how it effected if I validate data in class level or validate it in middleware level, or even  effect the  scalability
If I want to change some properties or  validation layer that means I should change the control request method
For that I'm wondering if I use joi in middleware vlidation that may be make loose coupling and add external layer for my architecture
In another hand if I use middleware that mean I should add joi validation for each route which means external code files

Comment: Well, performance will be the same. Don't care much about micro performance improvements (most of the time they are not worth it). Regarding your concerns about coupling. I'm pretty sure adding a middleware for validating it's not the best idea since some of your validations are Business Logic and you are moving that logic outside of your service. Also if you decide to change your delivery mechanism and implement websockets for instance you will ended up refactoring a lot (it happened to me), or duplicating your validation logic.

Comment: the creator of nest.js suggest using joi. But I like the class validator way, don't know why..https://github.com/nestjs/config/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

The [NestJs Pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) documentation page gives examples using both *Schema based validation* and *Class validator* techniques and doesn't appear to prefer one over the other. In most cases, following NestJs convention is preferred over the middleware technique used in your first example.

Depending on the number of entities and how often the requirements change, it could be difficult to keep your schemas synchronized using the first technique.

Your second example will likely be easier to maintain since your validation is defined with your entity. You don't have to remember to edit another file when the entity changes.

If you're using any 3rd-party packages it may have built-in support for one or the other. The `@nestjsx/crud` package, for example, uses NestJs's built-in `ValidationPipe` for Body request validation, making use of the class-validator and class-transformer libraries.

As @iván-sánchez suggested, this may depend significantly on your project structure. Your comment to his answer suggests several scenarios, so the best practice may vary.